# static declaration follows non-static

Tags: c, gcc, avr

in my avrstudio4 project i've got this error:

```
../Indication.c:95:15: error: static declaration of 'menu_boot' follows non-static declaration
```

in **main.c** i type **#include "indication.h"**

**indication.h** is a header file for **indication.c** and function is defined in it like this:

```
unsigned char menu_boot(unsigned char index, unsigned char *menu1) 
__attribute__((section(".core")));
```

in **indication.c** i've got

```
#include "indication.h"
...
unsigned char menu_boot(unsigned char index, unsigned char *menu1)
```

What should i do?

Comment: Should what's in your .c file also not have the `__attribute__((section(".core")))` after the signature?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148244/static-declaration-follows-non-static-declaration

Comment: Are you on a system where `Indication.c` and `indication.c` refer to the same file?  Your compilation error is in `Indication.c`, so unless the file system is case-insensitive, you're looking at the wrong file.  (Mac and Windows are typically case-insensitive.)   Does your version of GCC not tell you where the previous declaration is?

Comment: @rjayavrp: the x-ref'd question certainly covers the same issue.  The answers do not explain what is happening in much detail, though.

Answer (score 2):

Taken at face value, the error message means that at line 95 of file `../Indication.c` (which may or may not be the same file as the file named `indication.c` that you discuss), there is a static declaration for `menu_boot` such as:

```
static unsigned char menu_boot(unsigned char index, unsigned char *menu1);
```

or a static definition of it, such as:

```
static unsigned char menu_boot(unsigned char index, unsigned char *menu1)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Consider the following code in a file `xx.c`:

```
extern unsigned char function(int abc);

static unsigned char function(int abc);

static unsigned char function(int abc)
{
    return abc & 0xFF;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.1.2 (on RHEL 5), the compiler says:

```
$ gcc -c xx.c
xx.c:3: error: static declaration of ‘function’ follows non-static declaration
xx.c:1: error: previous declaration of ‘function’ was here
$
```

If I comment out line three, then the compiler says:

```
$ gcc -c xx.c
xx.c:6: error: static declaration of ‘function’ follows non-static declaration
xx.c:1: error: previous declaration of ‘function’ was here
$
```

The message is the same, but includes the information about where the previous declaration was.  In this case, it is in the same source file; if the declaration was in a different source file (typically, a header) included in the translation unit, then it would identify that other file.