# Porting linux C code to windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, include

I'm very blocked because I would like to porting a C code (running in Linux) to windows and I don't know how I could do this, the code has the following libraries:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>


#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


#include "openssl/conf.h"
#include "openssl/evp.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"


#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#include <m_string.h>
```

What I can do to port this code to Windows(running in 32 and 64)?, thank you

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need? Do you need to know what your possible solutions are? Or do you need help implementing a particular solution? Or what?

Comment: Yes and sorry, I forgot to ask a question, the next time I will do it

Answer (score 3):

There's no "magical wand" or "easy way" to do it.

If your code is not 100% POSIX-compliant (and as far as I know Windows doesn't support that terribly well), your code is not going to run on Windows without emulation or rewriting it.

You might try:

- http://www.cygwin.com/ - recompile your application with this
- A virtual machine on Windows
- See if a ported version of your sw exists
- coLinux stuff (http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableubuntu/) - 32 bit only
- Rewrite your app for Windows

From the above, some headers might be replaced with equivalent ones (hopefully), e.g. try `io.h` for some of the POSIX functionalities.. then you'll have to port linux sockets to Windows ones (and that's a relatively easy task). Openssl is multi-platform so no problem..

I don't know what `my_global` and `m_string` are, sorry.

Comment: Cygwin exists precisely for the purpose of providing a posix environment under windows.  In my experience, it does this very well.

Comment: Thank you for your soon response, at the beginning, the most of the libraries are compatible but this program use a Linux standard socket connection that maybe I must modify with winsock2. Now I found a problems with the famous my_global.h (MySQL library), the error appears when I try to compile the code through Eclipse (with MinGW+GCC), it say the following "static declaration of 'rint' follows non-static declaration", What Can I do to fix it?

Comment: Might be of help with that specific function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148354/1938163 - perhaps you can add a prototype to fix it.. something like a stub

Comment: I see this functions and it doesn't fix my problem because I guess is a problem related to my_global.h library or some compatibility error

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-March/054140.html - check that you don't have a definition for rint already and possibly try to comment something out to avoid that.

Comment: good job. I'm not familiar with that library so I can't tell you why the error has been fixed by that. For what you're doing right now take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740096(v=vs.85).aspx it basically explains how to port unix sockets to Windows equivalent ones.

Comment: thank you, I'm going to see the above link but MySQL error (with my_global.h) appears yet, I used to programming with Eclipse, maybe it is a compatibility problem?, I don't know, I heard something about Visual Studio is good for programing with C and MySQL

Comment: I recommend installing MySQL for Windows and including the appropriate headers, don't try to retain headers written for another platform.

Comment: Now, I've gotten to compile two libraries libusb (openssl in Windows) and openssl, there was two main problems, first, the library architecture because my Windows 8 is 64 bits and the second, was a mistake related to copying the static libraries in the right place because MinGW 64 bits organize the files in a strange order, the path is C:/MinGW/X86_64-w64-mingw32/include for headers, C:/MinGW/X86_64-w64-mingw32/include for .a files (64 bits) and C:/MinGW/X86_64-w64-mingw32/include/lib32 for .a files (32 bits). Now, I'm still working in the full solution

Comment: At the moment, the best solution was doing similar things in Windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a lot of pre compiler statements to exclude some parts of code and include others to make a code totally portable without modifications.